# How to change size of CGContextRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

How can I increase size of CGContextRef after its creation.

```
if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 0);
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
}
CGContextRef ctr = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Can i change size of ctr?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it without the if-else conditions. Create a CGContext using that last line of code only.

Here's a simple example

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100,100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need, I need to increase space for drawing.

Comment: Check [this](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/more_cocoa_examples/090-CGImage-scale.pl) link out. It helps you create the CGContext using makeContextOfSize